# phpmyadmin gives error with domain for login

Tags: nginx, directadmin

I have a server with centos 6.7 64bit os , nginx web server (php-fpm55) and DirectAdmin control panel (custombuild 2).
I want all domains hosted on server access to phpmyadmin.
Now phpmyadmin with IP opens, But with domain not opens
For example:
domain.com/phpmyadmin : 404 not found
Please help me about this.
Thank you...

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Which phpmyadmin version is installed on your server? Please check it at /var/www/html/ directory and try to create correct symlink to phpmyadmin directory.

```
ln -s /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-version /var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```